# How to install 3 different versions fo mysql in a single instance(Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to install 3 different versions of mysql-server in a single instance(Ubuntu).

1. MySQL server **5.6.24**
2. MySQL server **5.6.32**
3. MySQL server **5.7 latest release**

Can anyone tell me the process to install all the above versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are sevrel ways to do so, for example:

- **1 :** Install from scratch to an entirely different directory, change the port then install the other one
- **2 :** Use a container (like a virtual machine) and install inside then forward the port to another one in the machine

This [link](https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/setup-multiple-mysql-servers-with-different-versions-docker-du107solq) show the steps to do **2**.